# What is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the first time I have encountered this kind of error when I code and when I googled this error, the answers that were provided were very vague and not very useful to me. So I'm actually building this windows form application and I've already created a few classes. I haven't had this problem before and it came very suddenly and I do not what I did that triggered it.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public static store myStore = new store();

    [STAThread]

    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

When I commented out public static store myStore = new store(); I could run the program but nothing is being initialised on my Windows Form Application

This is the store class:

```
    class storeSystem
{
    // Creates a list to store cards (cards)
    public List<cardObject> myCardList = new List<cardObject>();

    // Creates a list to store image paths
    public List<string> imagePathList = new List<string>();

    public storeSystem()
    {
        createCardObject();
        initialisePicture();
    }

    public void createCardObject()
    {
        // Get data from txt file
        string[] cardInfo = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\Assignment\cardLists.txt");

        // Populate "cards" list
        for (int i = 0; i < cardInfo.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] cardData = cardInfo[i].Split(',');
            myCardList.Add(new cardObject(cardData[1], cardData[2], int.Parse(cardData[3]), double.Parse(cardData[4])));
        }
    }

    public void initialisePicture()
    {
        // Get image path from txt file
        string[] imagePath = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\Assignment\imagePath.txt");
    }
}
```

Sorry about the formatting!

Comment: This exception thrown when you have error in static constructor or static field initialization. Please add code for type `store` to make it more clear.

Comment: @AndreyTretyak done! Thank you for taking the time to read my code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your error is either an I/O error (one or both of those files don't exist or aren't accessible, etc.) or in the contents of `cardLists.txt`. More to the point that one (or more) of the lines does not split into five different string parts (`cardData[0]` - oddly unused; this could be part of your issue).

However, the biggest problem is an overall design issue - constructors shouldn't be doing a lot of processing and consequently throwing exceptions you aren't aware of. `createCardObject` and `initialisePicture` really shouldn't be called by the constructor.

Anyhow, in Visual Studio, set a breakpoint on the first line of the constructor and F11 your way to what's actually crashing and you'll get the full exception text and know what's doing it.

Comment: Okay thank you very much! I think I found and fixed my problem! As per your advice, I will think about the overall structure of my code and try to optimize it ^^!! Thank you for your time for reading my code!!

Answer (score 1):

[TypeInitializationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.typeinitializationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is thrown as a wrapper around the exception thrown by the class initializer.

In your code class `Program` during initialization calling constructor or `store` to fill static field `myStore`.

I can see four possible exception in constructor of type `storeSystem`:

1. File `F:\Assignment\cardLists.txt` could missing or protected from reading (FileNotFoundException, IOException, ...).
2. `Split` for file line could return array with less then four elements (IndexOutOrRange). Are you sure that first element of spited array should be skipped?
3. `int.Parse` could throw parsing exception if it's not integer.
4. File `F:\Assignment\imagePath.txt` could missing or protected from reading.

To find out exact reason check inner exception, or just debug solution in constructor of `storeSystem`.

For future consider avoiding action that could throw exception inside constructor, especially inside static constructor, and may be add some validation logic or `try/catch` for file opening.

Comment: Yes thank you! I checked my code and the problem was with number 2.! Thank you for taking the time to read my code, and I will add in some try/catch stuff inside!